# Redirect File Downloads to CDN

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, webserver

I want to redirect a file download from

```
mysite.com/setup.exe to supercoolcdn/setup.exe
```

I had earlier written some redirect rule myself,but it had resulted in loops and brought the website down eventually.

Can someone suggest me a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redirect rule like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ^setup\.exe$ http://cdn.com/downloads%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks.But i added                                                Redirect /setup.exe http://cdn.com/downloads/setup.exe                    It seems to work fine.Do you see any issues?

Comment: Sure that should work, I have also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay,But im a noob in Apache.I just entered the text exactly as in my previous comment ie: without the RewriteEngine and other stuff mentioned by you.Will this cause any loops or stalls?

Comment: Just copy/paste code in my answer "as is" into your root .htaccess on `domain.com`

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will copy it.For knowledge sake,if i use the code mentioned in my comment.what will go wrong?

Comment: That code will also work fine for this simple case. But `mod_rewrite` is more powerful and more flexible.